# How to list all snowflake tables stages

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I loaded 10 tables to my snowflake db. It was using the 'Load data' option in the web ui.

i used my csv files in my local.

The data got loaded successfully.

But when i query for the stages

list stages;

only the first table name is listed. I understand that should be the table stage of that first table.

Why are the stages which were created for other tables not listed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabari - Do not get confused between stages and tables. You can have 1 stage and  have multiple files present in the same stage. If all your files are present in the same stage, you can view them using the command `List stage @<stagename>`.

Answer (score 1):

SHOW STAGES only shows explicitly created stages (i.e. named stages) not table/user stages